# Create A Many-To-Many Relationship In A Test

Tags: django, selenium, django-testing, django-tests

I have a many-to-many relationship:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    modules = models.ManyToManyField(BaseModule, blank=True)

class BaseModule(models.Model):
    task_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I am loading in my fixtures test data, populating my 'BaseModule' database:

```
fixtures = ['test/fixtures/initial_data.json']
```

Then creating a User object, but I cant figure out how to create a relationship between a User and BaseModule.

Ive tried many things, including:

```
# this works, but creates a new BaseModule, I want to create a relationship with one generated in 'fixtures'
test = person.modules.create(topic='test')
test.save()

# this doesnt work
testModule = BaseModule.objects.get(pk=1)
person.modules.set(testModule)

# this doesnt work either
person.modules.create()
person.modules.basemodule_id = 1
person.refresh_from_db()

for module in person.modules.all():
    print("module.topic:")
    print(module.topic)
    print("end")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#this doesnt work
testModule = BaseModule.objects.get(pk=1)
person.modules.set(testModule)
```

You should add brackets []

```
testModule = BaseModule.objects.get(pk=1)
person.modules.set([testModule])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have no idea why on earth I needed those brackets, I am sure I havent used them before when calling set  :s .. Anyway, thank you

Comment: If you use `BaseModule.objects.filter(...)` instead of `.get(pk=1)`, you can skip brackets).